# Error al realizar una petición get a API REST

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-axios

**Problema**: tengo una API REST en `Django`, el problema no es general si no en una parte específica, cuando pruebo a realizar una petición sobre cualquiera de las URL de la api todo funciona correctamente, excepto para una en la que trato de guardar el contexto en una variable, me da el siguiente error:

> ​XHR failed loading: GET
> "http://localhost:8000/api/Usuarios/?search=Joselito"

**EDIT**: El error no se produce al ejecutar el mismo código en una clase de React, pero el problema me viene cuando trato de realizar la petición en una función exportada.

## Código de la petición:

```
  const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
  const setUserInfo = React.useContext(setUserContext);
  const userIsLoged =(Object.keys(userInfo).length) ? userInfo.first +" "+ userInfo.last  : null;
  
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = React.useState({});
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState({});

  const token ={
    usuario,
    password
  };

  function handleEnviar(){
    loginUser(token);
  }

  async function loginUser(credenciales) {
    console.log(credenciales.usuario);
    const url =
      "http://localhost:8000/api/Usuarios/?search=" + credenciales.usuario;
    var response = await axios.get(url);
    var data = await response.data;
    setUserInfo(data[0].nombre)
  }
```

Comment: Por que get y no post?

Comment: supongo que tienes un boton que llama loginUser().  A veces pasa de que el boton no esta definido como `type="button"` y hace que la pagina se refresque.

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford lo he probado de la misma manera y me da el mismo error

Comment: @Isaac tengo definido la propiedad ````type```` como tu dices pero el problema persiste

Comment: No es que te vaya a solucionar el problema usar post, simplemente, es como se debe hacer, segun el standar de rest para realizar cualquier operación que no sea meramente de lectura, por ejemplo para obtener una pagina a través del navegador usarias get.

Comment: Esto es porque el método get no admite transportar data mediante body y mandar datos personales a través de url podría ser un fallo de seguridad, por ejemplo cuando tienes una pagina que no quieres que se vea la proteges en todo caso con una api key y nunca usenarme y password o mejor, una session en el navegador con cookies o jwt.